# Custom CAF receiver html

Tags: html, google-cast

I'm building a webpage where I can upload an image and put a fog of war on top of it.

There are two views, one where the fog of war is semi-transparent and one where it's completely opaque. I'd like to be able to cast the opaque version.

So far, the only solution I've been able to get working is to render the opaque version on the server and then send a url to the chromecast to load that image using the default media receiver.

Is there a way to build my own receiver that could render an image and fog of war on a canvas? I've tried to find examples of custom html in the receiver, but all I've found so far is custom css styling.

Comment: Also, if this is a dumb question, please let me know. I'm just struggling to figure out how to get chrome cast to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://github.com/nlcamarillo/castDeck and from their code was able to get mine to work.